# Search list - Query term

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I tried to execute this code to get the Search list:

```
YouTube.Search.List searchList =youtubeService.search().list("snippet");
searchList.setMaxResults(50);
searchList.setQ("channelName");
searchList.setType(Collections.singletonList("channel"));
searchList.setPageToken("nextPageToken");
```

I tried to set 2 channel names but I get duplicated rows, how i can remove this duplicated in the query?

set the 2 channels' names for the same page, and get duplicated rows.

expected to get correct rows.

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube API is channel based.   When you authorization the App you picked a channel this is the channel you have access to.    If you want to access a different one you need to request authorization of the user again have them pick a different channel